# Android : Refresh ListView not working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I knew it was much to discuss about this issue, but my problem has not been resolved. In accordance with title, ListView wont refresh with code

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is from main.activity

```
verticalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),verticalActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("table","slide_vertical");
            intent.putExtra("pathConf","vertical");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is for verticalActivity.class

```
public class verticalActivity extends Activity {
private String tableActivity;
private String pathConf;
listAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<listActivity> items;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slidevertical);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String thisNewIntent = intent.getStringExtra("table");
    String thisNewPathConf = intent.getStringExtra("pathConf");
    this.tableActivity = thisNewIntent;
    this.pathConf = thisNewPathConf;
    DatabaseAdapter db = new DatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.openDataBase();
    this.items = db.getItem(thisNewIntent);
    final ListView obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listvertical);
    adapter = new listAdapter(this,items,tableActivity);
    obj.setAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object o = obj.getItemAtPosition(position);
            listActivity getObject = (listActivity) o;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), viewItemAct.class);
            intent.putExtra("type", "image");
            intent.putExtra("data", getObject.getPath());
            startActivity(intent);
            //Toast.makeText(verticalActivity.this,"Data = "+getObject.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
 }
public void refreshList(){
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

For listAdapter.activity

```
public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
//private Context context;
private ArrayList<listActivity> itemList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private String tableName;
Context myContext;
private Activity activity;
public listAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<listActivity> results,String tableName){
    this.itemList = results;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    //ViewGroup p = parent;
    if(convertView==null){
        //layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem,null,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.location = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        holder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.idItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iditem);
        holder.listImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.buttonDelete = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delButton);
        holder.buttonDelete.setFocusable(false);
        holder.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String idString = holder.idItem.getText().toString();
                DatabaseAdapter db = new DatabaseAdapter(myContext);
                try {
                    db.createDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                db.openDataBase();
                db.deleteData(idString,tableName);

                ((verticalActivity)activity).refreshList();

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    int id_ = itemList.get(position).getId();
    //String id__ = toString(id_);
    holder.idItem.setText(String.valueOf(id_));
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(itemList.get(position).getPath());
    holder.listImage.setImageURI(uri);
    String[] splitLocation = itemList.get(position).getPath().split("/");
    String nameFile = splitLocation[splitLocation.length-1];
    holder.title.setText(nameFile);
    holder.location.setText(itemList.get(position).getPath());
    holder.date.setText(itemList.get(position).getDate());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView location;
    TextView date;
    TextView idItem;
    ImageView listImage;
    Button buttonDelete;
}
}
```

from the above code there is a button to perform the deletion of data from the database, for the deletion of data from the database can already be done but for refreshing the ListView always fail. If there is something wrong with my code? Can someone help me?

> Thank's for your help guys. For the trouble I have a litle solution. I'm just refresh list for item from ArrayList<>.

`public void refreshList(){
        DatabaseAdapter db = new DatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            db.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.openDataBase();
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(db.getItem(tableActivity));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

> Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

In listAdapter Constructor insted of Contect pass the activity

```
public listAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<listActivity> results,String tableName){
    this.itemList = results;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.activity = context;
    this.myContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
}
```

and set the Button Id in getView() method

```
 holder.buttonDelete.setId(position);
```

onClick() of Button  place the following code

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
    public void run() {
    System.out.println("Deleted Id "+v.getId());
    itemList.remove(v.getId());
    System.out.println("Refresh the list Item ");
    notifyDataSetChanged();                             
 }
});
```

This will delete your item.  if u want different mechanism to handle your list view

[click Here!](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/03/simple-listview-with-viewbinder-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have a class variable **Activity activity** and you are never initializing it anywhere ... to call method refresh list, you need to call it on context that you passed through adapter constructor ...

```
((verticalActivity)context).refreshList();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: why ? did you read the code above ? he have an Activity variable not even initialized ...

Comment: Can you elaborate? This was just flagged as "low quality" by Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You are only deleting from db but not from itemList.

Use `itemList.remove(position)`

Comment: yes I know, but I want refresh list when deletion data successfully.

Comment: adapter is setting contents of listView based on contents of itemList not db. Also deleting from db will not change contents of itemList unless you reinitialize it. So you have to call itemList.remove(position) after db.deleteData(idString,tableName);